# What is an "installation script" in MSI?

Tags: windows-installer

Ofiicial Microsoft documentation refers some "installation script" in numerous places. Foe example, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Instead the installer writes the custom action into the installation
>   script.

I have carefully examined MSDN and a few books about MSI - and can't find clear definition what is this `installation script`, how it's related to `MSI` engine and how it's exactly

> installation script can be executed outside of the installation
>   session in which it was written

Is it some definition and documentation about this `installation script` or it is some undocumented `MSI` engine internals that are referenced just for bibliographic purpose?

Comment: This document might help http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php


Also include:
Use Install Sheild if you want to develop MSI/EXE installer programm. Link from where you can get it: http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm

Comment: This is very much a real question that gets into the fundamental theory of how Windows Installer operates.  InstallShield is simply an authoring tool that sits on top of Windows Installer and doesn't address the question.  I wish more people who wrote installers would have the curiosity to ask such questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Installer is a declarative (vs imperative) programming language.  Instead of writing "script" in some language you use table data to express the installation.  For example consider the tables:

Feature -> Feature Components - Component -Directory

Component -> File

You are telling MSI that when a given feature is installed, the components that belong to it need to be installed.   When the component is installed, a directory needs to be created and a file needs to be copied.  If the installer rollsback, the file and directory needs to be removed.

This is handled by various standard actions such as CreateFolders and InstallFiles.  We don't write any script to accomplish this.

But, there is in fact a script.  It's generated by Windows Installer itself at runtime.  Inside of any standard action that modifies machine state are two different phases:

Script Generation -  The installer is carefully considering what needs to be done and dynamically generating a list of operations to be performed

Script Execution - The installer is now executing that script.   Note: This occurs inside of InstallFinalize

Log your favorite installer and start looking through it for the InstallFiles action.  You'll see the two phases.

This is very important stuff to realize when writing your own custom actions.  For a lot more information on the subject, see:

[Installation Phases and In-Script Execution Options for Custom Actions in Windows Installer](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know, in what condition "installation script can be executed outside of the installation session in which it was written"?

Comment: Sure, deferred execution custom actions would be an example.  You have an immediate execution that has the ability to query tables, evaluate component action states and create a dataset that gets marshaled over to a deferred custom action.  The deferred then processes that dataset (CustomActionData) and only has access to write to the log.